# Null behavior in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, nullable

I'm wondering about the correct way to deal with a warning I'm see in VS2022 in a .net 6.0 project. I have the initialization for a class done in a separate method, i.e. not directly in the constructor.  But I get a warning saying: Non-nullable field 'Name' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor.  Consider declaring the field as nullable.

I don't want the Name field to be nullable, in other words, an instance of this class should always have a value for Name.  And the Init() method gets called from both constructors and sets this value.  If it helps, the warning number is CS8618.

There seems to be more than one solution to this, but what is the correct way to get rid of this warning ? I'd like to avoid having #pragma ignore warning ugliness in my code, so I wouldn't consider this a valid solution for me.

```
class ClassA {
  public string Name;

  public ClassA(int i) { 
    Init(i.ToString());
  }
  public ClassA(string s) {
    Init(s);
  }
  private void Init(string id) {
     Name = id;
     //lots of other stuff happening in this method
  } 
}
```

Comment: Actually, don't ignore the warning because it shows a different bug. Why is this field public? That's almost always a bug. Fields are implementation details and treated that way by serializers, data binding, validation. Use a property instead.

Comment: Another bug is calling an `Init` method instead of a constructor accepting a `string`. Instead of calling `Init`,  call `this(i.ToString())` in the definition ie `public ClassA(int i):this(i.ToString(){}`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos While it is a good recommendation to use a property, using it instead of a field would not remove the warning.

Comment: @Ray it would, if the second bug was fixed - calling the constructor instead of `Init`. The problem here is caused by *two* bugs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, if that's the only thing OP wants to do in `Init` - I assumed they have a real reason for an `Init` method and setting the name in there, though, and just overly simplified the code in which just setting the property directly in the ctor would of course be the best solution.

Comment: @Ray that would be a) a smell - constructors aren't meant for heavy lifting and b) no excuse for setting fields outside the constructor. Which is another smell. ReSharper or other analyzers would probably emit extra warnings for this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah. It would be great to know what OP really does in `Init`. I have the feeling a lot is missing in the example, as several required keywords were also missing previous to my edit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos is correct, this is a simplified piece of code, there are other things that need to happen in Init(), to where it doesn't make sense to duplicate this code in multiple constructors.

Comment: @scantrell Can you add a bit more of relevant code? You would not require to have an `Init` method or duplicate code if you _can_ call the `string` constructor from the `int` one as Panagiotis Kanavos suggested via `this(i.ToString())`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , I really appreciate the comments on ctor chaining, thank you.  The answer from Guru Storn and the doc reference just helped broaden my knowledge about nullability related patterns to apply to other scenarios besides this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not ignore nullability warnings whenever it is possible. In this particular case you can use [`MemberNotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullattribute?view=net-6.0) to help the compiler:

> Specifies that the method or property will ensure that the listed field and property members have values that aren't `null`.

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public string Name;

    public ClassA(int i)
    {
        Init(i.ToString());
    }

    public ClassA(string s)
    {
        Init(s);
    }

    [MemberNotNull(nameof(Name))]
    private void Init(string id)
    {
        Name = id;
    }
}
```

For other useful nullability analysis attribute - see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis).

Or use approach suggested by [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos) in comments - use constructor chaining:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public string Name;

    public ClassA(int i) : this(i.ToString())
    {
    }

    public ClassA(string s)
    {
        Name = s;
    }
}
```

Also note that usually it is recommended to encapsulate fields into properties.

Comment: A better idea would be to remove `Init` and call the string constructor from the int constructor

Answer (score 3):

You could also use a `get-only-property` for your property.

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public ClassA(int i)
    {
        Name = i.ToString();
    }
    public ClassA(string s)
    {
        Name = s ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `init` in case you set it from the constructor - just a getter is enough. (I also suppose the OP overly simplified `Init` and wants to do more than just setting `Name` there, so setting it outside of the constructor _may_ be meaningful.)

Comment: Yes your're right ... c hanged it to a get only property

Comment: And also now this class is immutable, which is good for lots of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Since only a single value is being set, why not do it in the constructor? Regardless, the solution is simple. Provide a default value.

**Option 1**:

```
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

**Option 2**:

```
private string _name = String.Empty;

public string Name
{ 
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
}
```

**Option 3**:

```
private string _name = String.Empty;

public string Name
{ 
    get => _name;
    set => _name = value;
}
```

---

According to [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):

> Prior to C# 8.0, all reference types were nullable.

According to [Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values):

[image]

and according to [Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)

> C# also provides the following built-in reference types:
>
> - dynamic
> - object
> - [string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types)

In .NET Framework 4.8, the following is permissible:

```
public string Name { get; set; } = null;
```

However, in .NET 6, this results in the following warning: `warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.`

In .NET 6, one needs to specify a default (non-null) value -  [String.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=net-6.0) can be used.

```
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

In .NET 6, if one would like to allow a null value for a `String`, do the following:

```
public string? Name { get; set; } = null;
```

---

**Resources**:

- [Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)
- [Reference types (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types)
- [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references):
- [Learn techniques to resolve nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-warnings)
- [String.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?view=net-6.0)
- [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)